# ROS (Jade) using anaconda python on OS X

Tags: ros, python, homebrew, anaconda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see from the [install instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source#Homebrew) that I should use the system Python, not the homebrew Python. I'm not interested in using homebrew Python. However, I'd very much like to use a conda python environment for ROS.

Is it advisable to then do `echo "$(brew --prefix)/lib/python2.7/site-packages" >> ~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/homebrew.pth`, analogous to what the install document suggest for the system python? The `site-package` of brew contain a bunch of modules that conflict with conda's modules (e.g. numpy).

It looks like homebrew is largely calling `pip` to install Python modules. If it calls the anaconda `pip`, then the modules should be installed under the anaconda environment's `site-package` folder, and not homebrew's, right? Is there any other mechanism that homebrew is using?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222992/ros-(jade)-using-anaconda-python-on-os-x/) by [gustavogoretkin](https://answers.ros.org/users/11151/gustavogoretkin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2015-12-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm by no means an OSX expert, but I do know that ROS doesn't seem to like Anaconda very much (or the other way around). I've seen multiple Q&A's where all sorts of strange problems were in the end 'solved' by *not* using Anaconda anymore. You could run into those kind of issues here as well.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0